# Vue.js - How to delete selected row by delete button in tbody?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I really understand vue.js, but my code didn't work well.
Now I have tried to delete selected row information by using delete button exist same row.
Even if I push the button in first row, never delete but I could delete from second row information.

I was using split method in my code.
I checked vue.js web site and I was using $delete method but it didn't work.

I really want to understand vue.js and Typescript.
Does any advise me?
My code is below.

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>username</th>
                    <th>delete</th>                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(user,index) in users" :key="user.id">
                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                    <td><v-btn class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteRow(index)">delete</v-btn></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Component,Vue} from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import axios from 'axios'

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue{
    users:any=[]
    deleteRow(index:any){
        this.users.splice(this.users,index)
    };
    async mounted(){
        const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
        this.users = response.data;
    }   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are not using `splice` properly. Your method should be:

```js
deleteRow(index:any) {
  this.users.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing `splice` with the parameters start as index and the second parameter for the deletes count:

```
 this.users.splice(index,1)
```